# Error at build on Dockerfile image build in hardhat project

Tags: hardhat, typescript, docker, build-from-source

I have my hardhat project that builds and run fine using yarn.
But when I try to execute "yarn build" from a Dockerfile during the image build process I have the following error:

### => ERROR [7/8] RUN yarn build                                                                                                                                                                  17.0s

> [7/8] RUN yarn build:
> #11 0.383 yarn run v1.22.19
> #11 0.420 $ npx tsc -p tsconfig.json
> #11 16.59 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers'.
> #11 16.59   The file is in the program because:
> #11 16.59     Entry point of type library '@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers' specified in compilerOptions
> #11 16.59 error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'.
> #11 16.59   The file is in the program because:
> #11 16.59     Entry point of type library '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle' specified in compilerOptions

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "tsconfig.*", "hardhat.*", "./"
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN yarn install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["npm", "run", "track:inventory"]
```

This is the content of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bot-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
    "dev": "npx ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test": "npx hardhat test",
    "track-inventory": "npx ts-node src/inventory/track.ts",
    "clear": "rm -r ./dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.2",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.7",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.5",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "10.2.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.10",
    "@types/sinon": "^10.0.13",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.4",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.7",
    "sinon": "^15.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.6",
    "@types/sinon-chai": "^3.2.9",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.1.1",
    "ccxt": "3.0.54",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethereum-multicall": "^2.16.1",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.2.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.13.0",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "prom-client": "^14.2.0",
    "rotating-file-stream": "^3.0.4",
    "tslog": "^4.8.2"
  }
}
```

And finally here it is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./typechain", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "types": ["@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers", "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.json"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Any help on how to make my docker build command succesfuly create the image?

Answer (score 0):

The type definition files for `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers` and `@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle` are missing during the Docker build.

Just remove the `--production` flag from the `yarn` install

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "tsconfig.*", "hardhat.*", "./"]
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN yarn install --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
EXPOSE 3000
RUN chown -R node /usr/src/app
USER node
CMD ["npm", "run", "track:inventory"]
```